# Getting around field shadowing

Tags: java, inheritance, field, overriding, shadowing

For a particular program, I essentially have an abstract superclass with several different subclasses.  However, I'm having trouble with field shadowing as illustrated below.

```
abstract class Super {
   String name;

   String getName() {
       return name;
    }
}
```

Now I create subclasses that each have their own "name".

```
class Sub extends Super {
    name = "Subclass";
}
```

However, creating instances of the subclass, and then calling the inherited method getName() will yield null due to field shadowing.

Is there an easy way to avoid this problem, and to allow subclasses to each have a unique field that can be accessed by an inherited method?

Answer (score 0):

Make the field visible in the child class and initialize it in the subclass constructor or in a subclass instance initializer.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this mechanism (bonus left to reader, extend code to get the name of the class directly).  The code use the Abstract classes constructor to set the name. You could also define a setName function in the Super class and use that.

**Super class (abstract)**

```
package stackShadow;
public abstract class Super {
    String name;

    public Super(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**Shadow1 class first subclass**

```
package stackShadow;
public class Shadow1 extends Super {
    public Shadow1() {
        super("Shadow1");
    }
}
```

**Shadow2 class second subclass**

```
package stackShadow;
public class Shadow2 extends Super {
    public Shadow2() {
        super("Shadow2");
    }
}
```

**Test class to test getName**
    package stackShadow;

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shadow1 one = new Shadow1();
        Shadow2 two = new Shadow2();

        System.out.println("Name for one is: " + one.getName());
        System.out.println("Name for two is: " + two.getName());

    }

}
```